# Customizing TextInputLayout's colors on 4.x doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm doing the following in my `syles.xml`

```
    <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/app_text_small</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/app_white</item>
    </style>
```

and then setting the style to the `TextInputLayout` like so: `android:theme="@style/TextLabel"`

My problem is that it won't set the colors of the bottom border to white, nor the floating text. At least not on 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 Any ideas? On 5.0 and above it works just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that pre Lollipop the OS doesn't know the `android:theme` attribute. So what I did was move all the custom attributes from the `TextLabel` style to the maine `style` that overrides the app compat one directly.

i.e. 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

This seemed to be just fine on pre Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style for your text appearance in this way.

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Implementation code for your layout is given below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_Email_Login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout code. In layout you need to implement this line. app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"

Comment: Yup. I set the `style` and also added the attribute line to the `TextInputLayout` view. I'm starting to think this might come from another place. Trying to think out of the box a bit ... any ideas on what else could make this not work? I'm using 25.1.0 dependencies for the app compat and whatnot ... so that SHOULD be fine, unless they had a bug in it, it's not really the latest version. hmm...

Comment: Once try android:textColorHint="#your color inside textinputlayout" and remove app:hintTextAppearance and let me know.

Comment: So it seems we're moving in the right direction. Now I'm getting this when the edit text is not focused http://puu.sh/vqGdz/b5801182eb.png and this when it is (so basically i still get the default color) http://puu.sh/vqGgR/7fe2ca89e4.png

Comment: try using the textcolorhint and textcolor for edittext also.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. This is getting frustrating. I wonder what the heck is going on ...